# Extremely low memory speed when replacing RAM

Tags: laptop, memory, lenovo-laptop

I recently attempted to upgrade the RAM on my Lenovo E495 from 8gb (8x1) to 32gb (16x2), both 2400MT/s. The memory was detected successfully by the BIOS of my device as well as windows Window 10 (all 32gb detected and passed memory testing and the speed is recognised). However, when doing a memory benchmark extremely degraded performance was found on the memory ([user benchmark profile](https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/24548542)), which is noticeable in certain applications.

Checking the frequency with CPU-Z instead of the BIOS or Windows utilities shows that the DRAM frequency is 400MHz, a third of the expected 1200MHz of 2400MT/s memory (which I know is supported as it is what the device originally shipped with). The device should support his memory as it is the same type used in other machines (if it is preinstalled) and the device can take the amount of memory ([forum post](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-13-E-and/Lenovo-E495-RAM-upgrade/td-p/4507813) and [load out on product page](https://www.lenovo.com/au/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-edge/E595/p/20NFCTO1WWENAU3/customize?)).

What would be the reason for these slow speeds and how could they be addressed?

Comment: You could be running into bottlenecks on the memory bus or with your CPU. Have you checked your motherboard's BIOS?

Comment: @Burgi Since it is a Laptop the BIOS is quite limited, but I am able to see that it does appear to support the memory config. Looking up the CPU (AMD 3500U) it shows that it can support that config and the bus should be fine since the motherboard is shared with the other models in the same lineup which use a 32gb config.